# Excel - Date Range includes given time of day (a better approach)

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

Given a set of DateTime ranges in excel, such as:

```
Start                  Finish
13/03/2012 10:00:00    14/03/2012 03:00:00
15/03/2012 08:30:00    15/03/2012 10:00:00
```

And some TimeSpan such as:

```
Start       Finish
07:00:00    09:00:00
```

How would you determine if the time span falls in some given date range?

An approach like this might be a start:

```
AND(B2 < DATEVALUE(TEXT(B2, "dd/mm/yyyy")) + TIMEVALUE("07:00:00"),
    B3 >= DATEVALUE(TEXT(B3, "dd/mm/yyyy")) + TIMEVALUE("09:00:00"))
```

Though it relies on the being able to provide the start/finish values explicitly as opposed to two dates in any order. A conditional on start <= finish would do, but seems like it's overly complicated.

Is there a better way?

**Edit**: Bonus points for a *simple* approach to finding the percentage of the date range that falls in the time span

Comment: Perhaps better suited to Super User rather than Stack Oveflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the number of hours falling in the time span (but it's definitely not *simple*!):

```
=MEDIAN(F2,G2+(G2<F2),MOD(B2,1)+(MOD(B2,1)<MOD(A2,1)))
-MEDIAN(F2,G2+(G2<F2),MOD(A2,1))
+(F2<G2)*(MOD(B2,1)<MOD(A2,1))*MAX(MIN(MOD(B2,1),G2)-F2,0)
```

If this is greater than 0, the date range falls in the time span, divide this by B2-A2 for the percentage.

e.g. Date Range: 6:00PM - 9:00AM, Time span: 7:00AM - 7:00PM returns 03:00 which is 20% of the date range.

Comment: Hello @lori_m, what if the Date range is 6:00PM - 9:00AM as you suggest but Time Span is 7:00AM - `8:00AM` - your formula gives me 2:00, shouldn't it be 1:00? I think you could use this version for the correct result `=(F2>G2)*(B2-A2)+SIGN(G2-F2)*((INT(B2)<>INT(A2))*(MAX(G2,F2)-MIN(F2,G2))+MEDIAN(MOD(B2,1),F2,G2)-MEDIAN(MOD(A2,1),F2,G2))`....[I'm assuming dates and times in A2 and B2, no more than 24 hours apart....]

Comment: Nice one! I've changed the last MOD(B2,1) to MIN(MOD(B2,1),G2) which I think now gives the same values as yours. Your formula is 23 characters shorter so i'd go with that one, the only possible benefit of the formula posted is it allows for a date range specified only by times.

Comment: @barry: Looking at this again, I think your formula can be simplified a little since 
`SIGN(G2-F2)*(MAX(G2,F2)-MIN(F2,G2))` is the same as `G2-F2`. So with a date range just given by times we could use: 
`=MOD((F2>G2)*(B2-A2)+(A2>B2)*(G2-F2)+SIGN(G2-F2)*(MEDIAN(B2,F2,G2)-MEDIAN(A2,F2,G2)),1)`. There is however some ambiguity if the timespan crosses midnight. For example if we swap the date range and time span in the example above, should the result be 1, 2 or 3 hours?

Comment: That looks good to me @lori_m, I like it! I think the amended version in your answer above can still give different results, so I'd favour this one - in my view the answer would be 3:00 for your suggested scenario, i.e. possibly counting hours at both ends of the period - that's certainly what my original does and your improved version of the same.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you're assuming that the dates will always be the same day, is that the case?

Try

`=AND(MOD(A2,1)<=F2,MOD(B2,1)>=G2)`

For percentage

`=MAX(0,MIN(MOD(B2,1),G2)-MAX(MOD(A2,1),F2))/(B2-A2)`

`Update:`

If the date range can be unlimited, 1 day or many, then you can use this formula to get the total hours within the timespan

`=(INT(B2)-INT(A2))*(G$2-F$2)+MEDIAN(F$2,G$2,MOD(B2,1))-MEDIAN(MOD(A2,1),G$2,F$2)`

that assumes that the timespan doesn't cross midnight - if timespan **may** cross midnight, e.g. could be 08:00 - 11:00 but could also be 22:00 - 03:00 then this formula should work

`=(F$2>G$2)*(B2-A2)+SIGN(G$2-F$2)*((INT(B2)-INT(A2))*ABS(G$2-F$2)+MEDIAN(F$2,G$2,MOD(B2,1))-MEDIAN(MOD(A2,1),G$2,F$2))`

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't have thought of this. But looking for any given date range, updated question to reflect this.

Comment: OK so what's the question exactly? Does the whole of the Timespan occur at least once (unbroken) within the date range? What's the maximum length of the "date range" could it be more than 24 hours?

Comment: Not assuming any limitations on ranges for my case, this is neat if the date range is defined as one day though.

Comment: @Kyle, OK I amended my answer based on your comment, adjusting the suggestion I made in my comment in lori_m's answer!

Comment: @barry: Nice tweak to allow for more days! In case the range includes non-work days, one could subtract something like `(INT(B2)-INT(A2)-NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)+1)*MOD(G2-F2,1)`. Also FWIW, I think a few charcters could be saved by factoring the `SIGN(...)` part outside everything else and replacing by `ABS()`: `=ABS((F2>G2)*(A2-B2)+(INT(B2)-INT(A2))*ABS(G2-F2)+MEDIAN(F2,G2,MOD(B2,1))-MEDIAN(MOD(A2,1),G2,F2))`.

Comment: I think this might be simplified in the general case: `=ABS((F2>G2)*(MOD(A2,1)-MOD(B2,1))+MEDIAN(F2,G2,MOD(B2,1))-MEDIAN(MOD(A2,1),G2,F2))+(NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)-1)*MOD(G2-F2,1)`

Comment: Oops, replace `ABS` by `SIGN(G2-F2)*` in the general case formula above.

Answer (score 0):

Say the date ranges are in columns A and B, and the Timespan in F2 and G2.
Apply the following formulas and drag down.

```
H2 = IF(AND($F$2>=RIGHT(A2,8),$F$2<RIGHT(B2,8),$G$2>RIGHT(A2,8),$G$2<=RIGHT(B2,8)),1,0)
```

Column H gives tells you if it's true for a particular date range.

```
I1 = SUM(H2:H4)/COUNT(H2:H4)
```

I1 gives you the percentage